# postgres stop a recursive search

Tags: postgresql, recursion

I'm doing a search using a postgres "with recursive" construct, but I want to stop after finding a single occurrence of something in the tree.  I'm not confident the "limit 1" on the calling select clause will do it.  What is the conventional approach?

Comment: Please **edit** your question and add your table definitions (`create table ...`), some sample data, the expected output based on that data and the query you have tried so far

Comment: `LIMIT 1` in the `SELECT` almost certainly *won't* do it, because it's not pushed down into the CTE. You need to write the recursive CTE so that once it finds one row it won't add more entries to the table.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I'm stuck.  Might be a mental block.

Comment: Here was my thinking.  You have to keep adding rows to the result to continue, so when you want to stop you add a row with a distinctive marker that the queries on all the other traversal paths will detect and quit. How to rewrite the query to return no results when that row exists thus far escapes me.